# How to pass the command from provider to change root into requested component?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, http-post, ionic3

In provider, I have a code like:

```
//TaskProvider.ts
doJob(){
  let body = (....);
  let jsheader = new Headers();
  jsheader.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  this.http.post(this.baseUrl+'/createtask', body, { headers: jsheader })
    .subscribe( data => { data.json().this.that;

// want to setRoot from here or make a function to order component to changing root.
    }
  },
   err => { 
    // navigation for unsuccessful task 
   }
  }
}
```

`Return Promise` or `Observable` doesn't work. Oh yeah, and `map` also not working with `Response` import

Comment: What do you mean by `set root`? This is not your typical observable structure in angular. Normally the service would return an observable and you would do the subscribe within a component. This way the component knows when the observable completes and has access to the returned data.

Comment: I am talking about changing root e.g. `this.nav.setRoot()`. Subscribing in component returns undefined. If I want to do it in components, full set of codes has to add there which will add more load to the pages and startup loading time will increase much. I just need page navigation idea from this `Provider`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call your `service` provider within your `component` and after that do the `page transition` (i.e. `setRoot()`). Don't do it inside the `service`. Which is very bad design.

**Note:** You need to remove `subscribe` from the `provider` and use `map` inside it as shown below.

Just an example extracted [**from this**](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-http-requests-with-observables). Please change according to your use case.

```
getComments() : Observable<Comment[]> {

         // ...using get request
         return this.http.get(this.commentsUrl)
                        // ...and calling .json() on the response to return data
                         .map((res:Response) => res.json())
                         //...errors if any
                         .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));

     }
```

*my-component.ts*

```
this.provider.doJob().subscribe(data => {
           //here do the page transition
    });
```

Comment: I tried it but it returns nothing. Maybe because I already subscribed in `provider`. What I did later is: call another function by `map` to do task in provider then in component I subscribed and navigated according to successful or unsuccessful return. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Yes, That is why I told you to remove subscribe from the provider and use it inside the component. You definitely use `map` operator with `HTTP` calls. Please see this: https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-http-requests-with-observables

Comment: Yeah this is what I did. I just used another function to do `(res:Response) => res.json(); "and other tasks"` and then used component to `subscribe` Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped :)